# Can trusting intermediate CA Cert allow communication with server using leaf certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Consider a Chain of Certificates where we have a root CA and multiple levels of intermediate CA certificates and leaf certificates at the end

Example:

Root CA Certificate -->Intermediate CA certificate 1 ->Intermediate CA certificate 2->Leaf certificate

Consider a server1 using a Leaf certificate. And at my client truststore I add "Intermediate CA certificate 1 or Intermediate CA certificate 2" certificate and make a https communication with server1 using leaf certificate .

Will https communication happen successfully by trusting the leaf certificate since at client side we have already trusted the intermediate CA certificate?

Comment: The implementation details will vary by software environment but, in general, as long as the server certificate chains to a *trusted* certificate it should be acceptable. Why you would trust an intermediate but not the root is unusual.

Comment: OpenSSL (which you tagged but didn't specify in the Q) originally did not accept an intermediate (non-root) cert in the truststore as an anchor; since 1.1.0 (2016) it can do so IF and only if you set the 'partial_chain' verification flag -- in code, which is ontopic here, that means an `X509_VERIFY_PARAM` object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is how certificate resolution works across the internet by having clients hold the root certificates.

If you trust the intermediate certificate, from the client's point of view the trusted intermediate becomes the root.

Comment: If you trust the intermediate it becomes an _anchor_, but not a _root_. Only a cert that is self-signed and thus has no 'parent' (superordinate) cert can be a root.

Comment: Ok, fair, but effectively the client trusts certificates signed by the intermediate.